# how can I terminate a specific thread in locust load-test

Tags: python, testing, load-testing, locust

I am new to Locust and I am testing a website with different users. 
How can I end end a user task ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you are after, but you can stop a user/locust by doing `raise StopLocust()`

Comment: thank you! that was actually what I want. some time work of some threads done and we need to terminate them

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by *end* a task, you specify your task with the `task` decorator like this that's all:

```
class MyBehavior(TaskSet):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyBehavior, self).__init__(parent)
        # E.g. set headers here
        self.headers = {}

    @task(1)
    def mytask(self):
        # Task starts
        self.client.get("/...", headers=self.headers)
        # Task ends
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the web version of locust, then to stop locust, you need to manually click on the Stop Button. OR you can call the `on_stop`
method in locust after desired number of users.

If you are using the non-web option, then you can use the timeout option in the locust command:

`locust -f --no-web -c 1000 -r 100 --run-time 1h30m`

The locust will stop after the specified amount of time